# Beamer: Transparent covered items in notes, but invisible in presentation

Tags: beamer, transparency, notes

Is it possible to have `\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}` for the normal presentation, but to have `\setbeamercovered{transparent=25}` in the notes page?

If so, how?

I tried adding `\setbeamercovered{transparent=25}` within `\setbeamertemplate{note page}`, and I have also tried adding `\AtBeginNote{\setbeamercovered{transparent=25}}` at various location, but that neither of those approaches appear to work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}

\AtBeginNote{\setbeamercovered{transparent=25}}

\setbeamertemplate{note page}{
    \setbeamercovered{transparent=25}
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{0.7\paperwidth}
            \insertslideintonotes{0.7}
        \end{column}
        \vrule
        \colorbox{blue!7}{%
            \begin{column}{0.3\paperwidth}~\\
                \insertnote~\\
            \end{column}
        }
    \end{columns}
}

\begin{document}
    \AtBeginNote{\setbeamercovered{transparent=25}}
    \begin{frame}
        \AtBeginNote{\setbeamercovered{transparent=25}}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Test 1
            \item<2-> Test 2
            \item<3-> Test 3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\AtBeginNote{\setbeamercovered{transparent=25}}` works for me.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Hmm... Where exactly do you put that command? It does not seem to work when I use it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @dexteritas: Sure, I have added an MWE now. :D

Comment: `\insertslideintonotes` only “copies” over the frame without rendering it again. You won't be able to have different transparencies here.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Aha, that's a bummer. So I assume what I am trying to accompolish is impossible then?

Comment: @nijoakim I don't know. Maybe there's a way to recall a slide and have it render again. `\againframe` does something similar. Let's wait for @samcarter or @josephwright who are the current maintainers and active here. The current implementation of `\insertslideintonotes` is fast (render once, shipout twice) and simple (just a transformation).

Comment: You could compile two different versions and then include the slides from the other version as image in the note page... not sure if this is worth the effort

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: That is a good idea! I might do that if I fail to figure it out some other way!